# Java Reflection NoSuchMethod exception when assigning implemented class to interface

Tags: java, reflection

Java Reflection

I have interface as following

```
public Interface A { void print();}
```

Inteface implementation as following

```
public class B implements A {

int abc =0;
public void setAbc(int abc){this.abc=abc;}
public int getAbc(return this.abc;);

void print(){
System.out.println("Hello world");
}

}
```

Now i assign child into interface as following

```
A a = new B();
```

using reflection i am trying to access child from parent as following

```
Class clazz = a.getClass()
clazz.getField("abc").set(a, new Integer(1456));
```

but i found no such method exception

any quick help  ? i am assinging child into parent b/c i have multiple implementations which contains different properties..

Comment: `NoSuchMethodException`? Are you sure? You are not referencing any method with reflection.

Comment: I assumed that it was really a `NoSuchFieldException`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getField()` method will only find the field if it's `public`.  You can use the [`getDeclaredField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) method, which will find the field if it's declared directly on the class, whether it's `public` or not.

When you say `getClass()`, you will get the runtime `Class` (here, `B`), even if the variable `a` is typed as the interface `A`.

Comment: awesome, i was able to access it but could not change it

Comment: BeanUtils.setProperty(customer,"firstName","Paul Young"); worked for me

Comment: call `field.setAccessible(true)` before setting or getting the value.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh - I had overlooked that.  It is necessary because the field isn't `public`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Field[] declaredFields = dtoKlass.getDeclaredFields();
```

Do Something like this. I use getDeclaredField() to do what you're trying to achieve.